# App icon missing after implementing Firebase Dynamic Links

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-dynamic-links

After implementing Firebase Dynamic Links, my app icon is missing.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I had combined the suggested intent filter on my main activity, which prevented the app icon from appearing.
Fix this by separating them like so:

```
<activity
    android:name=".activities.SplashActivity"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:screenOrientation="portrait"
    android:theme="@style/SplashTheme">
    <!--Main activity intent filter-->
    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
        <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
    </intent-filter>
    <!--Firebase dynamic links-->
    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />

        <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
        <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE" />

        <data
            android:host="@string/deep_link_uri"
            android:scheme="http" />
        <data
            android:host="@string/deep_link_uri"
            android:scheme="https" />

    </intent-filter>
</activity>
```

Comment: I always wonder how you guys discover these random solutions.

Comment: Me too Mofe, me too.. ‍♂️ https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Infinite_monkey_theorem